# Using pkg-config with Haskell Stack's Docker integration

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to build a Haskell Stack project whose `extra-deps` includes `opencv`, which in itself depends on [OpenCV 3.0](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) (presently only buildable from source).

I'm following the [Docker integration](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/) guidelines, and using my own image which builds upon `fpco/stack-build:lts-9.20` and installs OpenCV 3.0 ([`Dockerfile.stack.opencv`](https://gist.github.com/dukedave/3fa6104e09e9671674259a4d65e681c9)).

If I build my image I can confirm that `opencv` is installed and visible to `pkg-config`:

```
$ docker build -t stack-opencv -f Dockerfile.stack.opencv .
$ docker run stack-opencv pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.3.1
```

However if I specify this image in my `stack.yml`:

```
docker:
  image: stack-opencv
```

Attempting to `stack build` yields:

```
Configuring opencv-0.0.2.0...
setup: The pkg-config package 'opencv' version >=3.0.0 is required but it
could not be found.
```

---

I've run the build without the Docker integration, and it completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Dockerfile`](https://gist.github.com/dukedave/3fa6104e09e9671674259a4d65e681c9#file-dockerfile-stack-opencv-L26) is passing `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/usr`.

When running `docker build` the the `root` user is used, and thus `$HOME` is set to `/root`.

However when doing `stack build` the `stack` user is used, they do not have permission to see `/root`, and thus `pkg-config` cannot find `opencv`.

---

By removing the `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/usr` flag from `cmake`, the default prefix (`/usr/local`) is used instead. This is also accessible to the `stack` user, and thus `pkg-config` can find it during a `stack build`.